# Fitting a poisson distribution to a set of data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, poisson

I have the following set of data i'm trying to fit a poisson distribution to on MATLAB but all the outputs i get are zero and I'm pretty much stuck

```
data = [16  13  23  18  17  7   16  16  18  20 ...]
```

there's more but i'm not going to paste all of it. I do the following and the poisson distribution is built successfully:

```
 PD = fitdist(data,'Poisson');
```

my problem is here: I have the following set of x, and i'm trying to plot the poisson distribution:

```
x = [ 0.042 0.048   0.053   0.059   0.065   0.070   0.076   0.082   0.087   0.093   0.099   0.10 ... etc ]

y = pdf(PD,x)
plot(x,y)
```

The output of y is all zeros and I have no idea why this is happening. Any hints would be amazing.

EDIT:

My plot is supposed to be normalized and then a poisson process should be fit over it, so here's what i've done:

```
numbins = 20;
[frequecy, xout] = hist(data/norm(data), numbins);
binsize = xout(2)-xout(1);
bar(xout, frequecy/binsize/sum(frequecy));
hold on;
PD = fitdist(data,'Poisson');
stem(xout, pdf(PD,xout), 'r');
hold off;
```

if i change stem(xout,pdf) to the new x, then the plots won't overlap which is what I need to do.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using tags. Removed some unrelated tags.

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons why you get values (close to) zero.

- First of all the Poisson distribution is a [discrete probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution), meaning the PDF is zero for all nonzero-values.
- Further your sample has values between 7 and 20. You are asking for the probability for something below 0.1 to happen. Regardless of the discrete distribution you choose, you are asking for values far outside your sample range.

.

```
x=1:30
y = pdf(PD,x)
stem(x,y) %replaced plot with stem because it is discrete.
```

[image]

Here is how I would modify your code:

```
numbins = 20;
%Bin integers. You know your distribution only contains integers
%Hist with original scaling
[frequecy, xout2] = hist(data, min(data):max(data));
%scale later
xout=xout2/norm(data);
binsize = xout(2)-xout(1);
bar(xout, frequecy/binsize/sum(frequecy));
hold on;
PD = fitdist(data,'Poisson');
%sample your distribution using the unscaled x-values but plot scaled.
%multiply with numel(data) to get expected value instead of probability
stem(xout, pdf(PD,xout2)*numel(data), 'r');
hold off;
```

Comment: Note: non-integer values of `x` are explicitly left zero by the underlying [`poisspdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poisspdf.html#zmw57dd0e446971) function (at least on my R2015a). Regardless, +1.

Comment: Updated my answer, totally missed that a discrete distribution was used.

Comment: so then how would i go about fitting and plotting a poisson distribution to my data array? because the bar plot looks like it should fit to a poisson distribution.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Isn't fitting and plotting exactly what my answer does?

Comment: Let me edit the question so i can include pictures so my question makes more sense

Comment: @Ghazal Updated my answer.